# Related Rates (Right Triangle)

Tags: calculus

I have a related rates problem that reads as such:

> The top of a ladder slides down a vertical wall at a rate of 0.15 m/s. At the moment when the bottom of the ladder is 3 m from the wall, it slides away from the wall at a rate of 0.2 m/s. How long is the ladder?

So from this I'm able to determine:
$$
a' = -0.15,\quad
b' = 0.2,\quad
c' = 0,\quad
b = 3.
$$

How would I go about determining the length of $c$?

I have had some people suggest differentiating the pythagorean theorem, but as far as I can see, that just leaves me either dividing by $0$ (hah) or with the formula $a'a + b'b = 0$. Both are completely useless formulae.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
Your second formula is not useless: from
$aa'=-bb'$ you get $a=-bb'/a'$.

Comment: So if I allow the rate of the hypotenuse to eliminate the hypotenuse from the equation, I can use c = sqrt(((-bb')/a')^2 + b^2) to find the length of c.